# MySQL not storing some data when encountering special characters

Tags: mysql, special-characters

I have a site where users upload files, I parse them into different arrays and then store them in a MySQL database. The problem is that some special charcters — like ø or others from the French language, for example — cause the serialized array to not be stored as a whole.

For example, if the array was `AAAAAAAAAAAAAøbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccc`, I'll get `AAAAAAAAAAAAA` in the  database. The rest will be lost. Before I upload the serialized array, I `mysql_real_escape_string` it. Magic quotes are off, and the string is stored in a `Longtext` field with `utf8_unicode_ci` collation in a database with `utf8_unicode_ci collation`.

Here is the code that imports the string:

```
mysql_query("   INSERT INTO logs(uploaderid,date,randomstring,array1,array2,
  array3,array4)
    VALUES(
        '".$_SESSION['id']."',
        NOW(),
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($stringvalue)."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($array1))."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($array2))."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($array3))."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($array4))."'  
    )");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the data type for array1..array4?

Comment: Instead from program can you try to insert the data causing problem via mysql client program and post the outcome?

Comment: when i tried to manually import the outcome string of: echo mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($array1));  into the database through phpmyadmin all was stored right. ( ok the backslashes from escaped chars where not removed , but the special characters were stored corectly.) What does this mean ?

Answer (score -1):

In the end, what I did to "fix" (not the way I wanted it, but it works) the problem is that I changed the fields from `LONGTEXT` to `LONGBLOBS`.

Now there are no collations attached to the data and everything seems to work. Of course, on the downside, I can't see the data in the database since everything is now binary, but as I said before, it works!